# Were saints like Ramakrishna Paramhansa, Kabir, and others frauds because they said Hindus and Muslim pray to the same God

Tags: gods, bhakti, saint, islam

Let's be honest, the Hindu God is very VERY different from the God of Abraham that Jews, Christians and Muslims follow. Our God is a peaceful, compassionate, understanding and calm God while Abrahamic God is a jealous God who kills people for worshipping other gods. Our religions are not compatible, I hope everybody will agree.

Revered Hindu saints like Ramakrishna Paramhansa, Shirdi Sai Baba, Loknath Baba, Kabir, etc often stated that we pray to the same God. I remember reading in Ramakrishna Kathamrita that just like water is called jal by Hindus and pani by Muslims, God is called Ishwar by Hindus and Allah by Muslims. Most Hindu saints used to say that we all pray to the same God and tried to be 'secular' while no Muslim saint, even the well known Sufis, ever cared to be secular or say Muslim and Hindus pray to the same God. It is very clear that modern secularism is thanks to these saints that we have this 'Hindu Muslim bhai bhai' BS. So can we say without hesitation that these Hindu saints were frauds?

Comment: if there is ONE thing ALL religions agree upon, is that the universe can only have ONE GOD. Literally no religion says that there can be >=2 GODs (Supreme Being). Otherwise there would just be chaos. What they differ on is the method to attain this GOD, and also differ on whether there is ONE method or >=2 methods. Hindu religion is for those with Satvik mind, Christianity for Rajasik people, Islam for Tamo-guna. You can see why Muslims like to destroy, while Christians like to build, while Hindus like to preserve.

Comment: @mar Muslims won't agree on your theory. Plus, Swami Vivekananda affirmed that Muhammad couldn't have been a Yogi so he couldn't have realised God. The God of Abraham is very different from ours. Our Tamasic God is Ma Kali and she does not forbid people from worshipping other gods. Abrahamic God strictly prohibits praying to other gods

Comment: you misunderstood. Muslims will agree that there is ONLY ONE God. They may disagree on WHO that God is. Muslims do not say 'There can be multiple Allahs'. Hindus do not say 'There can be multiple Paramatmas'. Christians do not say 'There can be multiple Gods'. They all say, Universe has only One God. Difference is - They say 'My God/Allah is that GOD'. Hindus say 'There cannot be one God for Hindus and a separate God for you idiots'. So, these are only 3 possibilities. 1.Bhagavan < God/Allah. 2.Bhagavan > God/Allah, or 3.Bhagavan is same as God. Hindus believe option 3. Others believe option 1

Comment: @mar what no not at all! We believe there is one supreme truth whether it be an attainable principle ie Brahman or a deified supreme truth ie Ishvara or Bhagavan it is their. Ofc we can fight about forms and all that, but in no way do Hindus who are orthodox believe in Allah or Christ. Please stop this Hindus believe in all gods' nonsense. That being said Yoga texts allow for the worship of any positive form it doesn't mean that is the form of Ishvara.

Comment: @Haridasa - you still misunderstand. If there exists a Supreme Being called Allah/God (like they say), then Bhagavan = Allah =God. It's like saying a country can have only 1 king, not 2 or 3 kings. All religions agree that the universe cannot have more than one supreme being. they might say that 'my allah is the supreme being, not bhagavan or god', or they might say 'my god is the supreme being, not bhagavan or allah'. what we say is 'if you have a God/Allah who you say is the supreme ruler of universe, then He has to be the same as bhagavan, because there cannot be 2 supreme beings'.

Comment: Allah doesn't exist nor does YHWH as per the Hindu view though.